# Jmeter-Regular expression extraction-how to get the value of attribute name

Tags: jmeter

I have the below response from Rest service. I need do capture the value of dSecurityGroup which is "TEST" and pass it to next request. Can yu help on this

```
 "GenericResponse": {
    "Service": {
      "IdcService": "CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL",
      "Document": {
        "Field": [
          {
            "name": "xIPM_APP_1_9:isSetDefault",
            "value": "1"
          },
          {
            "name": "IdcService",
            "value": "CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL"
          },
          {
            "name": "dSecurityGroup",
            "value": "TEST"
          },
          {
            "name": "xIPM_APP_1_6:rule",
            "value": "IpmApp_1_Fields_Hide"
          },
          {
            "name": "dpTriggerField",
            "value": "xIdcProfile"
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use Response Assertion to extract out the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is invalid. check with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and update the correct JSON

Comment: Can you please check ```{
  "GenericResponse": {
    "Service": {
      "IdcService": "CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL",
      "Document": {
        "Field": [
          {
            "name": "xIPM:isSetDefault",
            "value": "1"
          },
          {
            "name": "****Service",
            "value": "CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL"
          },
          {
            "name": "dSecurityGroup",
            "value": "TEST123"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}```

Comment: @Shwetha try this ```$.GenericResponse.Service.Document.Field[?(@.name == 'dSecurityGroup')].value```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is [JSON](http://json.org/) therefore it doesn't make sense to use Regular Expression Extractor.

Consider using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead, it allows using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries which provide handy way to extract the "interesting" values from JSON responses.

In your case the relevant query would be something like:

```
$..[?(@.name == 'dSecurityGroup')].value
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)